# How do I unset/hide certain fields from being indexed by the core search module?

Tags: 7, hooks, search

If a content type has additional text fields, search core automatically indexes them because search core extracts all text from the result of `node_view()`

I can easily add extra index data via `MODULE_node_update_index( $node )`. This particular hook argument, `$node`, is passed by value and not by reference which means I can't unset certain items.

I hook into `node_view`, and alter it there but I don't want to change the output of the node normally, only when it's being indexed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Goto the **Manage Display** page for each content type (eg, admin/structure/types/manage/page/display).

Click on the tab for **Custom Display Settings**.

You will see the view modes that your system knows about.  Tick **Search Index** and save.

You can now configure which fields get indexed from the tab for that new display mode (eg admin/structure/types/manage/page/display/search_index)

Dump the search index from **Configuration -> Search -> Search Settings** ( admin/config/search/settings), and cron runs will re-index everything.  Or, do a `drush -y search-reindex; drush -y search-index` from the command line.

Start reading from [`node_update_index()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_update_index/7) which is invoked from [`search_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.module/function/search_cron/7), and you will eventually see a `node_view($node, 'search_index');`, which is how that display mode gets used.

Comment: If I do this and make no fields displayed for Search Index, will this eliminate that content type from showing up in search results?

Comment: @ChristiaNot sure, never tried that.  Pretty sure the custom_search module will handle this, though.  There should be one or more questions here about how to hide content types from search.